# Storing filesize in database vs calling filesize()

Tags: php, mysql

I keep my uploaded images all in one folder, each with a database entry that contains a link to the file, to the thumbnail, a name, comment etc.
I want to be able to display all this information, and other things like date (of upload) and filesize.
Should I include these last two variables in my database as well, or should I call the php-functions `filesize()` and `filemtime()` on the files when I need them? What are the (dis)advantages?
Thanks,
Pieter

Comment: either you "waste" space storing the info in the db, or you "waste" cpu/disk cycles calling `stat`. which of those is worse is up to you to decide.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it using space in the database; but you will need to factor in how to handle keeping the database's information in sync with the actual file info.

Comment: i suggest the second choice

Comment: If you only display info on web, either is ok. If you want to search via filesize etc, better store in db